# wordpress json api content key empty

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I've create a website for mobile with wptouchpro and wordpress, I access to the data thanks to the   [json api plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) of Wordpress. With this plugin i'm able to get content of some of my pages (the key 'content' send by my json api is not empty). But some other pages contains empty content whereas when I look the html data of those pages, the div of id "content" is not empty at all. Any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: The page you are trying to access may be restricted?

Comment: I don't think so. I can access it from a browser

Comment: May I see your website? And could you please tell the problematic url?

Comment: I can't show you my website. It works on my local network.